# Рекурсия, вызов функции без параметров

Tags: python, python-3.x

Задача найти второй максимум.

[image: вот сама задача]

Ссылка на источник: https://habr.com/ru/post/275813/

Меня интересует реализация на Python. Условие задачи в том, что нельзя передавать параметры в функцию, в этом то и проблема, ведь задача заточена на рекурсию. Возможно ли так сделать? На сайте приведено решение на Java, я не разбираюсь в Java, но там они передают параметры в функцию.

Сам код на Java:

```
public class Solution {
    public static void recursion(int max1, int max2) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = in.nextInt();
        // Базовый случай
        if (n > 0) {
            // Шаг рекурсии / рекурсивное условие
            if (max1 < n) {
                recursion(n, max1);
            } // Шаг рекурсии / рекурсивное условие
            else if (max2 < n) {
                recursion(max1, n);
            } // Шаг рекурсии / рекурсивное условие
            else {
                recursion(max1, max2);
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println(max2);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        recursion(0, 0); // вызов рекурсивной функции
    }
}
```

> Ещё, я не очень понимаю, как должен выглядеть ввод последовательности.

Comment: в `java` нет дефолтных значений параметров, а в питоне есть и там функция будет с заголовком: `def recursion(max1=0, max=2):` и вызов `recursion()  # вызов рекурсивной функции`

Comment: @gil9red т.е. я могу использовать дефолтные параметры функции в данной задаче?

Comment: Да, я написал в первом комментарии как они в питоне для функций задаются

Comment: @gil9red ввод последовательности происходит в самой функции, если говорить о языке Java в данной строке ```int n = in.nextInt();``` ? И какой ввод можно ввести, чтобы проверить работу программы на Java? Сколько пробовал, кидало ошибки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция без параметров для одного максимума:

```
>>> def remax():
...     n = int(input())
...     if n == 0:
...         return 0
...     return max(n, remax())
... 
>>> remax()
4
6
2
4
0
6
>>> _
6
>>>
```

Для двух максимумов получается такая

```
>>> def remax():
...     f = int(input())
...     if f == 0:
...         return 0,0
...     mm, sm = remax()
...     l = [f,mm,sm]
...     mm = max(*l)
...     l.remove(mm)
...     sm = max(*l)
...     return mm, sm
... 
>>> remax()
1
2
3
4
3
0
(4, 3)
```

Если вызвать как `remax()[1]` - получишь второй максимум

Comment: Очень познавательный для меня код, узнал, что оказывается можно присвоить параметры от возвращения значений функции, не додумался до этого, как вы сделали в строке  ```mm, sm = remax()``` и с удаление максимума из списка тоже интересно, спасибо

Comment: Это ж было в условии задачи- возвращение кортежа mm, sm= это распаковка кортежа

Comment: Тут есть ещё вариант, тот что скорее всего у автора учебника. Можно по возврату гонять все полученные значения